# Ruby on Rails - Destroy Action returns 404

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have some routes setup like this in route.rb

```
resources :users do
      resources :lists do
        resources :tasks
      end
  end
```

When I run  'rake routes' I can see the route for my destroy action:

> DELETE /users/:user_id/lists/:id(.:format)

My implementation of this action looks like this:

```
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
    @user.lists.find(params[:id]).destroy
     render json: { status: "success" }
  end
```

If I comment all the lines of this action except the 'render' line I will get the JSON result back. However with the lines in I recieve a 404. I'm pretty new to rails. Can someone please tell me what I have wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Put a breakpoint after the first line and see if it returns a user. And go from there. See where the error is begin thrown.

Comment: Break point? What IDE are you using that allows you to insert break points in your ruby? I am just editing these files using Sublime Text

Comment: just put 'debugger' on the line before: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/debugging_rails_applications.html

Comment: Are you using devise or custom user tables?

Comment: Good to know! The problem line appears to be this one: @user.lists.find(params[:id]).destroy

Comment: @suresh.g no, I'm not using any 3rd party gems

Comment: you must verify whether the action going inside destroy function, and value of @user. better use puts.

Answer (score 0):

Can you post what you have in your view? I suspect you need to specify a method in your link, e.g.: `<%= link_to "Delete", [@user, list], method: :delete, remote: true %>`

Comment: Actually I can't. This is an API that I am developing for mobile clients. It doesn't have a UI. I am making a DELETE http request however.

Answer (score 0):

try to use this may be it's helpful for you

```
<%= link_to 'Destroy', [user,list], method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %>
```

in your controller

```
def destroy
  @user = User.find(params[:user_id])
  @list = @user.lists.find(params[:id]) if @user.present?
  if @list.present? && @user.present?
     @list.destroy
     status = "success"
  else
     status = "fail"
  end
  render json: {status: status}
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
List.delete_all(["ID = ? AND user_id = ?", params[:id], params[:user_id]])
```

or `destroy_all`